# Easiest way converting swf banner ad to html

Tags: html, flash, banner

I have a flash ad banner (swf) that is way to big for the websites that will publish it. They´re guidelines say the max is 50 kb but the banner is 350 kb.

They told me to make a html banner and link the graphic to another hosting - But I´m old school and just have a few hours to deliver the banner.

What is the easiest way to do this? - Is there a converter I can transform the swf to html file?

Any solution for this problem is appreciated - The format doesn´t matter as long as it´s below 50 km

Answer (score 0):

Try Swiffy, it will convert a swf file to an HTML5 file:
https://developers.google.com/swiffy/

If that doesn't get you the results you need, you can try to convert the swf into a video and embed it using HTML that way: https://www.flash-banner-converter.com/